# Order zero maps in matrix algebra

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $a$ and $b$ are two elements in a $C^*$algebra $A$. We say $a\perp b$ if $ab=ba=a^*b=ab^*=0$. We say a completely positive map $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ is of order zero if for any positive elements $a,b \in A$, $a\perp b \Rightarrow \phi(a) \perp \phi(b)$.

Suppose we consider only matrix algebras (i.e. $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ for some $n$). Does there exists, nontrivial order zero cp maps? By nontrivial, I mean not maps like $a \mapsto uau^*$, where $u$ is an unitary (or isometry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the structure theorem of Winter-Zacharias (http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3290) any c.p.c. order zero map $\phi:A\to B$ has the form
$$\phi(a) = h\pi(a) = \pi(a)h,$$
where $\pi:A\to M(C)$ is a $*$-homomorphism from $A$ to the multiplier algebra of the C*-algebra $C$ generated by the image of $\phi$, and $h$ is a positive element in $M(C)$ that commutes with the image of $\pi$. If both $A$ and $B$ are matrix algebras, say $M_n$ and $M_m$, then you have
$$\pi:M_n\to M_m$$
which is either trivial (i.e. zero) or injective, since $M_n$ is simple. In the latter case of course you need $m = kn$, $k\in\mathbb N$ (plus some degeneracy that I'm neglecting here), and $h$ in this case is just $\phi(1_{M_n})$. So loosely speaking, $\pi$ is, up to a unitary conjugation, a $k$-fold embedding of $M_n$ into $M_m$, so that $\phi$ will look like
$$\phi(m) = h^{1/2}u(m\otimes 1_{M_k})u^*h^{1/2},\qquad\forall m\in M_n.$$

Comment: Minor correction: The image of $\phi$ need not operate non-degenerately. Therefore there can be some zero blocks. So one has $m=kn+l$ and $\pi(m) = diag(\underbrace{m,...,m}_{k},\underbrace{0_{1\times 1},...,0_{1\times 1}}_{l})$ up to conjugation with some unitary matrix $u$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I have specified in the answer, I decided to neglect this situation and assume that $n|m$ for simplicity. But of course you're right that that is the most general situation.